# Debugging Mixed mode (C# , C++) application

Tags: c#, windbg, crash-dumps, sos

I am debugging an issue with a mixed mode (managed and unmanaged) application.

The actual issue is within the unmanaged code.

I have loaded SOS dll into Windebugger. But is shows me the call stack only upto managed mode since i have loaded SOS dll. How do I see the call stack of unmanaged code as well?

Answer (score 4):

The SOS command `!dumpstack` will produce a complete stack trace with managed and unmanaged code. Since it's an issue in unmanaged code, the usual debugger stack trace commands (`k` and variants) may also be useful.

Answer (score 2):

!sosex.mk will give a complete stack trace in a way that is easy to read.

Comment: it says IXCLRDataStackWalk::Next failed. Error = 0x80004002

Comment: Is this a full memory dump?  What does !sos.clrstack say?

Comment: Yes it is full memory dump. clrstack shows callstack only upto managed code.